# phpDocumentor и метод с неизвестным числом аргументов

Tags: php, phpdoc

Есть метод с неизвестным заранее числом аргументов, причем первый и второй аргументы обязательны и должны иметь определённые значения. Я хочу задокументировать это, но не знаю как:

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $param_1-$param_x
 */
public function some_method() {
    $args = func_get_args();
}
```

Или я в корне не прав, допуская такой способ передачи аргументов и нужно передавать переменное количество аргументов массивом: `some_method($name, $type, array $param)`?

Comment: Докумнетация, она для того, что бы по прочтению было понятно, что со всем этим делать. На это и надо ориентироваться. Если параметры обязательны то их желательно напрямую указать в объявлении функции как вы и предложили. А все остальное не так важно.

Comment: @E_p ну тут наверное вопросы к моему IDE PhpStorm, но ему не нравится документирование параметров, которых реально нет в объявлении метода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с PHP 5.6 используется новый синтаксис для неизвестного количества аргументов, без использования функции `func_get_args()`. В этом случае можно все подробности описать в рамках директивы `@param` для аргумента `...$args`

```
/**
 * @param string $name ...
 * @param string $type ...
 * @param mixed $args ...
 */
public function some_method($name, $type, ...$args) {
    // foreach($args as $arg) { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Третий аргумент - массив строк, как я понял:

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $otherParams...
 */
public function some_method() {
    $args = func_get_args();
}
```

Comment: `string[] $otherParams... ` Имеет смысл когда все остальные параметры строки. В документации php использует `mixed`.

Comment: @E_p, в вопросе ТС вроде пытается намекнуть что остальные параметры - это строки, вот и поставил массив строк.

Comment: @Other третий параметр - не массив, а неизвестное количество строк. т.е. `some_method($name, $type, $p1, p2, p3, ...)`

Comment: @toxxxa, а сигнатура функции в примере говорит что массив. Ладно, сейчас исправим.

Comment: @Other нет, в конце я просто спросил "может быть неизвестные параметры плохая практика и не выделываться, а передавать массивом"

Comment: @toxxxa, OK....